# Show HTML table with Flask and render_template

Tags: python, html, flask, pymysql

I would like to show a table on a website using Google Cloud SQL and Google App Engine. 
I am using Flask and pymysql. To show the result of my query I use the render_template of Flask.

I already found other similar topics here (like [Topic: Listing table results to HTML with Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863584/listing-table-results-to-html-with-flask)), but I still get an error when I deploy my app. It seems that the error has to do with the for loop.. The error says "jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected".

Here's the full error message I get:

```
ERROR in app: Exception on /analysis [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise      raise value
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request      rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request      return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/srv/main.py", line 61, in analysis      return render_template("analysis.html", result = result)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 134, in render_template      return _render(ctx.app.jinja_env.get_or_select_template(template_name_or_list),    File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 869, in get_or_select_template      return self.get_template(template_name_or_list, parent, globals)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template      return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template      template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 125, in load      code = environment.compile(source, name, filename)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 591, in compile      self.handle_exception(exc_info, source_hint=source_hint)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception      reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise      raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/srv/templates/analysis.html", line 23, in template      <p class="p1"><span class="s1"><span class="Apple-tab-span"> </span>{% </span><span class="s2">for</span><span class="s1"> r </span><span class="s2">in</span><span class="s1"> result %}</span></p>
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 497, in _parse      return Parser(self, source, name, encode_filename(filename)).parse()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 901, in parse      result = nodes.Template(self.subparse(), lineno=1)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 883, in subparse      rv = self.parse_statement()
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 125, in parse_statement      self.fail('tag name expected', token.lineno)
File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/parser.py", line 59, in fail      raise exc(msg, lineno, self.name, self.filename)  jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: tag name expected
```

My Code in main.py:

```
    import logging
    import os
    from flask import Flask, render_template
    from flask import request
    import urllib.request
    from urllib.parse import parse_qs, urlparse
    import platform
    import pymysql
    import datetime

    db_user = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_USERNAME')
    db_password = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_PASSWORD')
    db_name = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_DATABASE_NAME')
    db_connection_name = os.environ.get('CLOUD_SQL_CONNECTION_NAME')

    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/analysis', methods=['GET'])
    def analysis():
        if os.environ.get('GAE_ENV') == 'standard':
            unix_socket = '/cloudsql/{}'.format(db_connection_name)
            cnx = pymysql.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password,
                                  unix_socket=unix_socket, db=db_name)
        else:
            host = '127.0.0.1'
            #unix_socket = '/cloudsql/{}'.format(db_connection_name)
        cnx = pymysql.connect(user=db_user, password=db_password,
                                  unix_socket=unix_socket, db=db_name)
        with cnx.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = 'SELECT * FROM content'
            cursor.execute(sql)
            result = cursor.fetchall()
        cnx.close()
        return render_template("analysis.html", result = result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

File analysis.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>contentID</th>
  <th>timestamp</th> 
  <th>clientID</th>
  <th>content</th>
</tr>
{% for r in result %}
<tr>
  <td>{{ r[0] }}</td>
  <td>{{ r[1] }}</td> 
  <td>{{ r[2] }}</td>
  <td>{{ r[3] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Do you have any suggestions what I can can change to make it work?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That's a very strange error. Is this definitely representative of your HTML template?

Comment: yes, the above code is exactly my html template. In all other comments / topics / tutorials it is described like I did above but it still doesn't work. Do I have to import or install something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the stack trace, the text editor you're using for `analysis.html` isn't a plain text editor. It's saving the file in some other format, making it invalid Jinja2 syntax.

So this line that you see in your editor:

```
{% for r in result %}
```

Python will see as (based on the stack trace; added some line breaks for clarity):

```
<p class="p1">
<span class="s1">
<span class="Apple-tab-span">
</span>
{% </span><span class="s2">for</span><span class="s1"> r </span><span class="s2">in</span><span class="s1"> result %}
</span>
</p>
```

To fix the problem, open the file `analysis.html` in a plain text editor and edit it as needed.

Comment: That was it, thank you so much! I didn't know that the Mac TextEditor changes the code from what I see in the program to something else.

Answer (score 4):

One way you can do this is by first have an object, or use pandas to read_csv and then use the dataframe's to_html method.

This saves a ton of time if your data is already formatted correctly:

```
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, render_template

@app.route("/table-page", methods=['GET'])
def table():

    data_dic = {
        'id': [100, 101, 102],
        'color': ['red', 'blue', 'red']}
    columns = ['id', 'color']
    index = ['a', 'b', 'c']

    df = pd.DataFrame(data_dic, columns=columns, index=index)
    table = df.to_html(index=False)
    
    return render_template(
        "at-leaderboard.html",
        table=table)
```

Now you take the HTML string and paste it into you template without send it as JSON or a dict needing Jinja template formating:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      {{ table | safe }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be an accepted answer...clean and very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for r in result %}

<p class="p1">
<span class="s1">
<span class="Apple-tab-span">
</span>
</span><span class="s2">for</span><span class="s1"> {{ r }}</span><span class="s2">in</span><span class="s1">
</span>
</p>

{% endfor %}
```